# SwiftUI updating class sub variables

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want an easy way to update UI state with the use of a single state variable.
Lets say I have a class Position that instance variables x and y.
Imagine I have a UI view that looks something like this...

```
@State var position: Position
var body: some View{
    VStack{
        Text("x: \(position.x)")
        Text("y: \(position.y)")
    }
}
```

I would like to maintain a single state variable of Position that can update both the x and y like shown above. But, as you may know this code will not update the x and y values on the UI View if they do change inside this position variable.

Does anyone know a way to update this view everytime x and y changes without having to have individual State variables for both x and y or is this the only way?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know a way to update this view everytime x and y changes without having to have individual State variables for both x and y or is this the only way?

The `Position` should be `struct` to have behaviour as you need, like

```
struct Position {
  var x: CGFloat
  var y: CGFloat
}
```

in such case whenever any of `x/y` changed the single `@State var position` will update the view.